# IBMMQDotnetClient using windows credentials instead of application specified credentials

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

In using IBMMQDotnetClient v9.2.0.1 in .NET Core, I attempt to connect to a client using

```
private MQQueueManager Connect()
{
    System.Collection.Hashtable properties = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "username");
    properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
    // more settings below
    
    return new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName, properties);
}
```

The issue is this still attempts to pass my personal windows credentials even after having set the userid and password when configuring the queue manager properties. How do I ensure that the credentials passed by the application replace my personal windows creds when running the application.

Edit:

For more context, the output options are configured as:

```
public static readonly int OUTPUT_OPTIONS = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
```

I am not sure if there can be other options that can ensure the passed creds are used as opposed to the windows creds.

Comment: What version of MQ is running on the queue manager you connect to?  IBM added CONNAUTH (connection authentication) to MQ in v8.0 and this would need to be configured on the queue manager with `ADOPTCTX(YES)` in order to use the ID/PW you send.  If it is configured with `ADOPTCTS(NO)`, then it will still validate your provided username/password, but for permission purposes it will use the user the program is running under.

Comment: @JoshMc it is running 9.1.4.0

Comment: You would need to check with the MQ admin to see what error they are seeing and if/how they have CONNAUTH configured.  The ID that is sent to MQ in the connection flow is always the logged in user, if you specify USER_ID and PASSWORD this is sent in addition to the logged in user during a subsequent MQCSP flow.  If the queue manager is configured to look at the MQCSP or not is what you need to check.

Comment: If you simply want to have a user sent over during the connection flow (no password) then you would need to do use runas or impersonation.  Note that if this works, then this means the queue manager is not secured as it is trivial to get the connection flow to send any username you want.

Comment: @JoshMc I have the permissions on my windows account to access the queue, so it works when I run it locally; however, when I try to push it to a remote server to access a queue my windows account (nor the server credentials) have access to, instead using a username and password configured for access to that queue, the instantiation of the queue manager object fails and says the host is not available. This is because it is trying to use the server credentials instead of the specific creds we passed in that would allow it to connect. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: Yes and it aligns with the behavior I mentioned in my comments above.  You can't force the queue manager to authenticate and user your ID and PW, the queue manager needs to be configured to do this.

Comment: @JoshMc Is it possible to configure the Queue Manager to only apply the ADOPTCTX(YES) to one queue in the manager? There are many applications using many queues in this QM. THanks for your help!

Comment: No that is a Qmgr Wide setting on the AUTHINFO object pointed to by the QMGR CONNAUTH attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future that runs into a similar situation I wanted to give an update on my resolution. I ended up running the IIS server with the credentials that were authenticated with MQ as opposed to a Network Service and this fixed the issue. This allowed me to use the queue manager that had already been set up, without changing its settings in any way.

Comment: This also points out the larger issue that anyone that has access to connect to that queue manager can easily provide the required username and succeed.   Configuring CONNAUTH with ADOPTCTX is a much better option.